# gem install XYZ locally (without connection to the internet)

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, offline

I need to install `win32-api` and `antlr3` on a computer without internet connection. Had it such a connection, I'd use gem like so:

```
gem install win32-api -r
gem install antlr3 -r
```

This won't obviously work. So, I thought there should be a way to download the *gem* and install it later, but I am not sure how I would proceed.

I found gem's `which` operator, which seemd to indicate the local location of a gem:

```
c:\>gem which antlr3
c:/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/antlr3-1.8.8/lib/antlr3.rb
```

however, it didn't work on win32-api:

```
c:\>gem which win32-api
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library win32-api
```

although I have previously installed it.

Can someone hint at the right direction to go on from here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try,

> gem install --local path/to/file.gem

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with this on a VM.  The VM intentionally did not have Internet access (sneaker-net test machine) but it still had some DNS servers configured.

For example:

```
$ gem install bundler-1.7.7.gem --local
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENETUNREACH)
    Network is unreachable - sendto(2) for "192.168.1.10" port 53
```

`192.168.1.10` is the DNS server that VirtualBox configured.  So what I had to do is comment out `/etc/resolv.conf` with ; at the beginning of all the lines.  Even leaving in Google DNS would break it.

```
; /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8  ; nope.  gem install --local doesn't like it
; You will get a Network is unreachable - sendto(2) for "8.8.8.8" port 53
```

If you comment out all of /etc/resolv.conf then you can install gems locally (from a file) it seems.

```
$ gem install bundler-1.7.7.gem --local
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.7
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.7.7
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.7.7
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/': no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
1 gem installed
```

Ruby gems version: 2.4.4 on Ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: I solved it by removing the default, hard-coded value in the gem-handling code.

Answer (score 0):

`gem` will first look in the current directory after `.gem` files. Try downloading the `.gem` files of the gems you want to install on a computer with an internet connection (and don't forget dependencies), then move the files over to the other computer and run `gem install xyz` in the same directory where you placed the `.gem` files.