# Install Rubygems without internet connection

Tags: ruby, linux, installation, compass-sass, offline

Is there a way to install **compass** and **compass_radix** offline?

I get the following when I attempt a command line installation:

```
sudo gem install compass
WARNING:  Error fetching data: bad response Service Unavailable 503 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
WARNING:  Error fetching data: bad response Service Unavailable 503 (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
    Compass is charityware. If you love it, please donate on our behalf at http://umdf.org/compass Thanks!
Successfully installed compass-1.0.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for compass-1.0.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for compass-1.0.3...

sudo gem install compass_radix
WARNING:  Error fetching data: bad response Service Unavailable 503 (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass_radix' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: compass_radix
```

Comment: Are you able to access the internet otherwise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758541/gem-install-xyz-locally-without-connection-to-the-internet?rq=1

Comment: @kaybee99: yes. Access is limited due to proxy/firewall restrictions

Answer (score 2):

If it's a firewall issue, you can also download gems directly via browser:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/compass
- https://rubygems.org/gems/compass_radix

Note that you will need those gems' runtime dependencies as well.

The other alternative is to download them from a computer where you do have internet access using `gem fetch`

```
gem fetch compass
gem fetch compass_radix
```

If the second scenario, put those files on a USB key and bring them over to the other computer without internet and install using the format

```
cd <directory where gemfiles are>
gem install ./compass-x.x.x.gem
gem install ./compass_radix-x.x.x.gem
```

You should store all gems in the same directory (compass, compass_radix and all runtime dependencies) before attempting `gem install <gemfile>`.